# how to use sql server with laravel in cpanel

Tags: laravel-8, cpanel

my .env

work in local xampp with add php_pdo_sqlsrv_74_nts_x64.dll

but not work in cpanel get error `could not find driver (SQL: select * from [your_database])`

how to add php_pdo_sqlsrv_74_nts_x64.dll or like it on cpanel

[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server] -> how to add it

with thancks

Comment: DB_CONNECTION5=sqlsrv_report
DB_HOST5=my ip static
DB_PORT5=1433
DB_DATABASE5=my database
DB_USERNAME5=user
DB_PASSWORD5=password

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

this may be PDO_SQLSRV extension missing issue kindly check to create a file in the public directory called info.php with this below code

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Call it in the Brower. Search for PDO_SQLSRV

Comment: PDO_SQLSRV not founded , how to add it ?

Comment: are u trying to add in php and sql server?